# MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with index (`year`, `foo`), where I would like to select the X largest observations of `foo` where `year == someYear`.

My approach was

```
df.sort_index(level=[0, 1], ascending=[1, 0], inplace=True)
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[2002, :10], :]
```

but I get

```
KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (0)'
```

I tried different variants of sorting (e.g. `ascending = [0, 0]`), but they all resulted in some sort of error.

If I only wanted the `xth` row, I could `df.groupby(level=[0]).nth(x)` after sorting, but since I want a set of rows, that doesn't feel quite efficient.

What's the best way to select these rows? Some data to play with:

```
                   rank_int  rank
year foo                         
2015 1.381845             2   320
     1.234795             2   259
     1.148488           199     2
     0.866704             2   363
     0.738022             2   319
```

Comment: What happens if you just sort using `df.sort_index(inplace=True)`?

Comment: @ASGM That works, but since I'm not ascending then, I'll get the wrong group of `foo`.

Answer (score 16):

Firstly you should do sorting like this:

```
df.sort_index(level=['year','foo'], ascending=[1, 0], inplace=True)
```

It should fix the KeyError. But `df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[2002, :10], :]` won't give you the result you are expecting. The loc function is not iloc and it will try to find in foo indexes 0,1..9. The secondary levels of Multiindex do not support iloc, I would suggest using groupby. If you already have this multiindex you should do:

```
df.reset_index()
df = df.sort_values(by=['year','foo'],ascending=[True,False])
df.groupby('year').head(10)
```

If you need n entries with the least foo you can use `tail(n)`. If you need, say, the first, third and fifth entries, you can use `nth([0,2,4])` as you mentioned in the question.
I think it's the most efficient way one could do it.

Answer (score 6):

`ascending` should be a [boolean or a list of booleans](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), not a list of integers.  Try sorting this way:

`df.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace=True)`

Comment: From the link: `ascending: bool or list-like of bools, default True`

Comment: Thanks @Jthorpe; I don't know if I missed that or if the documentation changed. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

To get the `xth` observations of the second level as wanted, one can combine `loc` with `iloc`:

```
df.sort_index(level=[0, 1], ascending=[1, 0], inplace=True)
df.loc[2015].iloc[:10]
```

works as expected. This does not answer the weird index locking w.r.t. lexsorting, however.

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked by using `sort_index(axis=1)`:

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

Once you do this, you can use `slice` or `pandas.IndexSlice`, e.g.:

```
df.loc[:, idx[:, 'A']]
```